# Transitivity-like Results in Group, Ring, Module, Field and Galois Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

I am reading Michael Atiyah and Ian Macdonald's *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*. On page 28, Proposition 2.16 says:

Suppose $A,B$ are rings, $N$ is a finitely generated $B$-module, $B$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module (using a ring homorphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ to restrict scalar) then $N$ is a finitely generated $A$-module.

I think this can be rephrased as transitivity of finite generated property of modules. The proof is straightforward. The thing that really interests me is that this result involved some flavor of transitivity and it reminds me of some other results involving transitivity including:

**(Transitivity of Characteristic subgroups)** If $G_{1}\supseteq G_{2}\supseteq  G_{3}$ are groups, $G_{3}$ characteristic in $G_{2}$, $G_{2}$ characteristic in $G_{1}$, then $G_{3}$ is characteristic in $G_{1}$.

**(Transitivity of integral propery)** If $R_{1}\supseteq R_{2}\supseteq R_{3}$ are rings, $R_{1}$ is integral over $R_{2}$, $R_{2}$ is integral over $R_{3}$, then $R_{1}$ is integral over $R_{3}$.

**(Transitivity of algebraic property)** If $F_{1}\supseteq F_{2}\supseteq F_{3}$ are fields, $F_{1}$ is algebraic over $F_{2}$, $F_{2}$ is algebraic over $F_{3}$, then $F_{1}$ is algebraic over $F_{3}$.

Also, there are some **FALSE** transitivity result that beginning students like me hope to be true but definitely is not true:

**(Non-transitivity of Normal subgroups)** If $G_{1}\supseteq G_{2}\supseteq  G_{3}$ are groups, $G_{3}$ normal in $G_{2}$, $G_{2}$ normal in $G_{1}$, then $G_{3}$ is not necessarily normal in $G_{1}$.

**(Non-transitivity of Galois extenstion)** If $F_{1}\supseteq F_{2}\supseteq F_{3}$ are fields, $F_{1}$ is Galois over $F_{2}$, $F_{2}$ is Galois over $F_{3}$, then $F_{1}$ is not necessarily Galois over $F_{3}$.

My question is to ask whether there are other important results and FALSE statements that have some flavor of transitivity, especially in the setting of group, ring, module, field and Galois theory. This will definitely benefit me for learning new concept and studying new examples and non-examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to analyze the non-transitivity of Galois extensions a little, you can also say that normality in field extensions is not transitive, but separability is.

In ring theory, the relation "is an ideal of" is not usually transitive (although it is for certain types of rings, in particular von Neumann regular rings.)

Maybe these are too trivial, but the relations "is a subring of" and "is a submodule of" are also transitive relations.